# using generic class in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I need implement a collection (for example, `SpecCollection`) which should contain `KEY` and `VALUE`. The key should be a composite key. Please see the short implementation:

```
public class CompositeKey<TId, TName>
{
    private TId _id;
    private TName _name;

    public TId Id { get; set; }
    public TName Name { get; set; }
}
```

I should initialize my collections only by the following way:

```
SpecialCollection<CompositeKey<string, int>, DateTime> e = new 
    SpecialCollection<CompositeKey<string, int>, DateTime>();
```

or like this:

```
SpecialCollection<CompositeKey<DateTime, int>, SomeClass> e = new 
    SpecialCollection<CompositeKey<DateTime, int>, SomeClass>();
```

Please let me know how can I declare my collection if it is possible?

I have found the following way:

```
public class SpecialCollection<TId, TName, TValue> 
    : Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName>, TValue> 
{
    private Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName>, TValue> _baseDictionary = new 
        Dictionary<CompositeKey<TId, TName>, TValue>();
}
```

But in this case I can initialize the collection object only like this:

```
SpecialCollection<DateTime, int, string> col = 
    new SpecialCollection<DateTime, int, string>();
```

Do you have any ideas how to declare the collection?

Thanks!

Comment: Me neither? What's your problem? What do you want ?

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to use `CompositeKey<>` as a type parameter to `SpecialCollection<>` without specifying the types.

Comment: I need implement a collection which I can initialize only like this: `SpecialCollection<CompositeKey<AnyType, AnyType>, AnyType> e = new 
    SpecialCollection<CompositeKey<AnyType, AnyType>, AnyType>();`

The key of the collections should be The key of the collections should be necessarily `CompositeKey`

Comment: Bobson, you said exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do exactly what you want - the .NET compiler can't partially intuit type parameters for generics.  This leaves you with three choices.

1. **Do nothing**.  The way you have it working now is the standard way to implement something like this.  You get the key type you want (`CompositeKey<Tid, TName>`) automatically.
2. **Give up the types of `CompositeKey<>`**.  In this scenario, you accept any `CompositeKey` as a `TKey` value.  To do this, you need either a non-generic base class for `CompositeKey` or an `ICompositeKey` interface.  You will be unable to access the types of the `Tid` and TName`inside`SpecialCollectioN<>` though, because you're not specifying any types it can use.

   ```
   public class SpecialCollection<TKey, TValue> 
       : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TKey : CompositeKey
   {
       private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _baseDictionary = new 
           Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
   }
   ```
3. **Specify *four* type parameters.**  In this way, you force the first type to be a `CompositeKey<Tid, TName>`, and the `SpecialCollection<>` will know what the types of it are.  On the other hand, you have to specify all four, because C# can't do partial generic type inference. (i.e. it's all or nothing).  Note that you *can* change the order around to whatever makes the most sense to you.

   ```
   public class SpecialCollection<TKey, TValue, Tid, TName> 
       : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TKey : CompositeKey<Tid, TName>
   {
       private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _baseDictionary = new 
           Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
public class SpecialCollection<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : CompositKey
{
}

public abstract class CompositeKey
{
    protected CompositeKey(object id, object name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public object Id { get; private set; }

    public object Name { get; private set; }
}

public class CompositeKey<TId, TName> : CompositeKey
{
    public CompositeKey(TId id, TName name)
        : base(id, name) { }

    public new TId Id
    {
        get { return (TId)base.Id; }
    }

    public new TName Name
    {
        get { return (TName)base.Name; }
    }
}
```

The abstract non generic `CompositeKey` class gives you a limited access to your `Id` and `Name` property in your `SpecialCollection` class.

But I think you should consider your first thought, because then you have the type safety you maybe need on `Id` and `Name`.